# BlueprintJS Tree add key prop

Tags: reactjs, web-component, blueprintjs

I am using BlueprintJS UI components for my ReactJS webapp.
I want to get rid of the warning when using the Tree component to render a file explorer:

`Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of "Tree"`

In the [documentation of the Tree component](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tree) I can find a `key` attribute which might be the thing I am looking for, but I can't get the warning away.

`node: [
        {
            hasCaret: true,
            iconName: "folder-close",
            label: "Folder 0",
            key: '1e'
        }
    ]`

Eveb this simple structure for the tree gives the warning to me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `node` is being passed into the `Tree`'s required `contents` prop. If you look at the [ITreeNodeInterface](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tree.tree-node-interface), you'll see that there are number of required fields that your object is missing. You have to have the following:

- `depth`
- `id`
- `label`
- `path` (questionable if this is truly required though: see this [ticket](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/1437))

You seem to be missing `depth`, `id`, and `path`. I'm not sure if `path` is truly required, but for starters can you try adding `depth: 0` and `id: 1e` to your object? You can probably get rid of `key` since that's optional.

As an aside, that warning is not so innocuous. It can often result in mysterious React behavior because it's not able to figure out which components actually need to be updated.

Comment: I supplied `id`, `path`,  and `label`, which seems enough